# Any interface to access linux's tc flower from another kernel module?

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, tc

I was looking at linux tc flower source code. I see that when a flow is modified, a netlink message is sent from user space to kernel space to create/delete/modify the flow. Rather than the userspace triggering those, I would like my kernel module (which I'm building) to do the same. But I don't find any interface to access tc flower functions. Almost everything is defined statically.

So, is there any interface to access tc flower kernel functions from another kernel module?

If my post is irrelevant to this community, please suggest me an appropriate one.